# Should I use new BASE64Encoder() or Base64.getEncoder() to encode images in java?

Tags: java, image, base64

In Java we find both classes `Base64` and `BASE64Encoder` to perform base64 encoding on bytes via

`Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(someByteArray);`

and respectively:

`new BASE64Encoder().encode(someByteArray);`

I am trying to base64 encode an image file, which will return a relatively large String (6k-7k character long base64)

Is there any convention to using one above the other, any performance differences or other reasons to use one above the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Base64.getEncoder()`. The `sun` packages (where `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` resides) are unsupported and their use is discouraged.

See [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs that Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html):

> The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface.
>
> A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.

Eclipse might already be showing you an `Access restriction` error and most classes from these packages [won't be accessible from Java 9 on](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/get-ready-jdk9).

[Performance-wise it also seems advisable to use the new implementation](http://java-performance.info/base64-encoding-and-decoding-performance/), although I haven't done any tests myself:

> Everything is evident from the table: appalling performance of sun.misc classes, acceptable performance of Commons Codec classes and very good performance of both iharder.net and MiG Base64 implementation. New Java 8 encoder/decoder is running faster than any other implementation (but you need Java 8...). javax.xml class turned out to be a hidden gem!

Comment: But is there any difference in performance? Or is it simply the exact same function except unsupported? Then why is there any reason you'd use the sun one, ever? (also using IntelliJ, so no access restriction error)

Comment: `Base64` exists since Java 8, before most probably only knew external libraries (like Apache Commons). I guess that was the main reason for people using `BASE64Encoder`. I updated my answer in regards to performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I wasn't sure as I couldn't find much on the internet, I guess it's always a safest bet to use the vanilla Java features and avoid sun, stay in the shadow. Awesome!